# Using global variable from one python file to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created 3 python files in a folder. Here are each of the files and their contents:

> one.py

```
products="testvar"
def oneFn():
    global products
    products=[1,2,3,4,5]
    print("one Function")
```

> two.py

```
import one

def twoFn():
    one.products.append(100)
    print(one.products)
    print("two Function")
```

> test.py

```
from one import *
from two import *

if __name__=="__main__":
    oneFn()
    twoFn()
    print(products) # testvar
    print(one.products) # [1,2,3,4,5,100]
```

Why is **products** and **one.products** returning different values?

Comment: `import *` is generally bad practice, be careful.

Comment: This is a great question because it shows how confusing imports can become if you are not careful.

Answer (score 3):

`from one import *` pulls in all exported names from module `one` into the current namespace. It does so, by creating (or overwriting) variables in the local namespace that (initially) refer to the same objects as the variables from the imported module.

However, it is still possible to assign different values to the variables within the main module without affecting the references in the imported module and the other way round.

If you re-assign a variable within a module *after* importing it, that modification will not be visible in the importing module.

Hence, within `oneFn()`, you overwrite the `products` reference in the `one` module. This does not affect the `products` reference in the main module.

The `global` in `oneFn()` just makes `products` within the function to refer to the one from the outer namespace and is more or less irrelevant wrt. to the behaviour you experience. If you write

```
from one import products
import one
one.products = 'othervalue'
```

You still get `products == 'testvar'`, locally.

Comment: Yes @dhke, just like you say `from one import *` is importing everything from `one.py` and making it essentially a local variable.